# Issue while configuring DNS with Portal for ArcGIS

Tags: linux, domains, apache, tomcat, arcgis-portal

**Steps followed**:-

1. Portal for ArcGIS 10.4.1 (Linux SUSE) Installation
2. ArcGIS Web Adaptor (Linux SUSE) Installation
3. Configuration of Portal with Web Adaptor (Web adaptor is configured on Apache Tomcat 7.065):

   - Portal is accessible using fully qualified machine name.
   - Portal is further configured with SAML: Portal is accessible through SAML successfully
4. DNS Configuration in Web Adaptor to access portal using DNS name: Portal is accessible using DNS successfully.

**Problem**:-

One of our web application (build using web app builder developer edition 2.2) is using spatial analysis widget (Buffer) and requires authentication for execution.  Without DNS i.e., using fully qualified machine name (machinename.domain.com) it is giving login option for both SAML and Portal identify store but with DNS (appname.domain.com) the authentication option is only portal identity store and no SAML?

As we have configured DNS after portal installation and ESRI documentation says for assigning friendly portal name, assign the name to the portal machine before you install the software. Then use the friendly name when setting up the portal. Do we have to change portal machine name before Portal for ArcGIS installation?